# How to opt out of sharing AWS EMR Studio Notebook's telemetry when use CodeWhisperer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-emr-studio, amazon-codewhisperer

I am using Amazon EMR version "emr-6.15.0". I am hoping to onboard CodeWhisperer in the AWS EMR Studio Notebook.

[This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio-codewhisperer.html) describes the permissions required for CodeWhisperer when use it in the AWS EMR Studio Notebook.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "CodeWhispererPermissions", 
          "Effect": "Allow", 
          "Action": [ "codewhisperer:GenerateRecommendations" ], 
          "Resource": "*" 
        }
     ] 
}
```

[This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codewhisperer/latest/userguide/sharing-data.html) tells how to opt out of sharing AWS EMR Studio Notebook's telemetry when use CodeWhisperer.

[image]

However, it also says

> Pausing the sharing of client-side telemetry will be valid only for the duration of the current AWS Glue Studio Notebook.

(I think "AWS Glue Studio Notebook" inside should be "AWS EMR Studio Notebook")

I am aware of it won't share the code content, however, I hope opt out of sharing telemetry for AWS EMR Studio Notebook at once too.

I was checking if there is a way to opt out by IAM or on EMR Studio level when using Terraform [aws_emr_studio](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/emr_studio). But had no luck.

Is there a way or config to globally opt out of sharing all AWS EMR Studio Notebook's telemetry when use CodeWhisperer? Thanks!